# how to lock the size of a Stage in java

Tags: java, javafx, locking, size, stage

I made a very simple java application with 3 scenes and 3 buttons.
button3 (b3) opens a popup but I set the image to lock size but the window can still be changed by using the mouse on one of the corners.
is there a way to lock the size so the curson can't edit this?

Here's the simplified code (just to get and idea)

```
public class Handler extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception { 

        Button button1 =  new Button("AD");

        VBox layout1 = new VBox(button1);
        layout2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        Pane layout2 = new Pane();
        layout3.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url(ad.jpg);" +
                        "-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;" +
                        "-fx-background-size: initial;");



        Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout1);
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(layout2);

        //Stage (window)
        primaryStage.setTitle("Basic Handler");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.show();

        button1.setOnAction(event -> {
            Stage PopUp = new Stage();
            PopUp.setHeight(266);
            PopUp.setWidth(474);
            PopUp.setTitle("Sponsored AD");
            PopUp.setScene(scene2);
            PopUp.showAndWait();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in your stage :

```
PopUp.setResizable(false);
```